# Can a non-resident apply for a Schengen visa from Turkey?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, turkey, netherlands

I am an Indian citizen and am travelling to Turkey for volunteer work for about 45 days and I want to travel to Netherlands in between.
Can I get Schengen visa from Turkey as I don't have enough time to apply from my home country India ?

Comment: In general, you cannot, unless you have a compelling reason for not applying in your country of residence.  It does not appear that you have a compelling reason, though if your trip to the Netherlands is motivated by some recent development that is beyond your control, such as a family illness, you would have a better chance of success.

Comment: @phoog any reason you don't make that comment an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Copying phoog's comment — In general, **you cannot**, unless you have a compelling reason for not applying in your country of residence. It does not appear that you have a compelling reason, though if your trip to the Netherlands is motivated by some recent development that is beyond your control, such as a family illness, you would have a better chance of success.